# Как структурировать базу данных?

Tags: база-данных

Задача сделать базу данных для риэлторской компании. Проблема в том, что когда добавляю в базу к примеру "Квартиру" у нее около 30-35 характеристик, думаю будет непродуктивно сделать таблицу с 35 столбцами. Как структурировать базу данных, чтобы сильно не грузило сервер?

Comment: EAV. XML/JSON. Sparse table. У каждого варианта свои плюсы и минусы. Изучай матчасть, и выбирай.

Answer (score 1):

Квартира и её характеристики, это соотношение "многие ко многим". Квартира может иметь несколько характеристик. Одна и та же характеристика может присутствовать у нескольких квартир.

Характеристики могут быть, как обязательными (например площадь), так и необязательными. Собственно последние и будут приводить к появлению пустых полей в записях.

Один из самых распространённых вариантов решения этой проблемы. Завести отдельную таблицу с перечнем характеристик и ещё одну таблицу, которая будет хранить `id` квартиры, `id` характеристики и значение характеристики.